# Ember-data failing to load relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

I'm having trouble loading some related models with ember-data. I'm pretty sure this is a syntax error on my part, but I just can't see it. Perhaps someone could be a second set of eyes for me?

The specific problem is that related models are not being displayed in my template.

Without further ado:

## Notes

- I'm using `ember-appkit-rails`.
- This is my first ember project, so please forgive my n00bness.
- I have a feeling that the answer may have something to do with embedded: 'always', but I have no idea how to integrate that into my code.
- DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0 ember.js?body=1:3462
- DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.f482da04 ember.js?body=1:3462
- DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 ember.js?body=1:3462
- DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.0 ember.js?body=1:3462

## The problematic template

I'd think that this should work. It's almost right out of the ember-appkit-rails generators. The librettist and composer names are not appearing.

```
<h3>{{id}}</h3>

<p>{{link-to 'Edit' 'operas.edit' this}} <button {{action destroyRecord this}}>Destroy</button></p>

<ul>
  <li>Title: {{title}}</li>
  <li>Alternate Title: {{alternate_title}}</li>
  <li>Source: {{source}}</li>
  <li>Librettist: {{librettist.name}}</li>
  <li>Composer: {{composer.name}}</li>
  <li>Notes: {{notes}}</li>
</ul>
```

## Models

#### opera.js.es6

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  alternateTitle: DS.attr('string'),
  source: DS.attr('string'),
  librettistId: DS.attr('number'),
  composerId: DS.attr('number'),
  notes: DS.attr('string'),
  composer: DS.belongsTo('composer'),
  librettist: DS.belongsTo('librettist')
});
```

#### librettist.js.es6

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  operas: DS.hasMany('opera')
});
```

#### composer.js.es6

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  operas: DS.hasMany('opera')
});
```

## ActiveModel Serializer

```
class OperaSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true

  attributes :id, :title, :alternate_title, :source, :librettist_id, :composer_id, :notes
  has_one :composer
  has_one :librettist
end
```

## Sample JSON being returned

This is what I see when I look at one opera record, but the structure holds for the entire set:

```
{
  "composers": [
    {
      "id": 4097,
      "name": "Müller, Wenzel"
    }
  ],
  "librettists": [
    {
      "id": 1414,
      "name": "Bäuerle, Adolf"
    }
  ],
  "opera": {
    "alternate_title": "oder Wien in einem anderen Weltteile",
    "composer_id": 4097,
    "id": 4166,
    "librettist_id": 1414,
    "notes": "these are some notes",
    "source": "F116.Theater.a.d.Wien.260A.Mus; Mus.Hs.78.Mus; Mus.Hs.25409.Mus",
    "title": "Aline Königin von Golkonda"
  }
}
```

I've also tried this approach with inline embedding (`{opera: {...composer: {...}}}`) but that didn't work any better.

Thanks for your help!
Paul.

Comment: Or is the correct solution to not embed but to make separate queries, one for operas, one for composers, and one for librettists, and let Ember match them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `_id` are not necessary if you're using the `RESTAdapter` as your client-side adapter.

```
App.Opera = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  alternateTitle: DS.attr('string'),
  source: DS.attr('string'),
  notes: DS.attr('string'),
  composer: DS.belongsTo('composer'),
  librettist: DS.belongsTo('librettist')
});

App.Librettist = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  operas: DS.hasMany('opera')
});

App.Composer = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  operas: DS.hasMany('opera')
});
```

JSON

```
{
  "composers": [
    {
      "id": 4097,
      "name": "Müller, Wenzel"
    }
  ],
  "librettists": [
    {
      "id": 1414,
      "name": "Bäuerle, Adolf"
    }
  ],
  "opera": {
    "alternate_title": "oder Wien in einem anderen Weltteile",
    "composer": 4097,
    "id": 4166,
    "librettist": 1414,
    "notes": "these are some notes",
    "source": "F116.Theater.a.d.Wien.260A.Mus; Mus.Hs.78.Mus; Mus.Hs.25409.Mus",
    "title": "Aline Königin von Golkonda"
  }
}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/233/edit

If you're using the `ActiveModelAdapter` then you'd use the `_id` in the json, here's an example with the `ActiveModelAdapter`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/234/edit

Comment: Thanks! But Mind = Blown. Why would removing the ID attributes make this work? Or: why _wouldn't_ this work by including the composerId and librettistId attributes?